# Javascript - Lists created through user input with a sort button

Tags: javascript, html, list, sorting, input

What I want: User types word into input bar -> user presses Add button -> word is added to two lists "unsortedUL" and "sortedUL" - > user presses Sort button -> the list "sortedUL" gets sorted by descending (z-a), while "unsortedUL" remains exactly how the user inputted it.

I cannot figure out how to get TWO lists while only ONE of them is sorted.

```js
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write a word!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sortedUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("sortedUL");
  switching = true;
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {           
        shouldSwitch= true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString();
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: green;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: number;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-align: center;


  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

input {
  border: none;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.sortBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Assignment Two</title>
<body>
  <h1 style="color:white;"align="center"id="date"></h1>
  <h1 style="color:white;"align="center"id="time"></h1>

  <div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2 style="margin:5px">Enter a list of words</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Word...">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
    <span onclick="sortList()" class="sortBtn">Sort</span>
  </div>

  <ul id="sortedUL">
  </ul>
  <ul id="unsortedUL">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce your problem to a more minimal example and consider providing a fiddle (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I should clarify, currently I need to add code that let's me duplicate the inputted words into a list called "unsortedUL" that will NOT be sorted when the user presses the Sort button. If you copy and paste this into a txt.html document and run it with with a browser, you should be able to see how the website functions, what works and what I need.  Here is a link to the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hdu49u53/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clone the HTML Node to append it twice.
Or create it twice like I did.

```js
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function newElement() {
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write a word!");
  } else {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    li.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("sortedUL").appendChild(li);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    li.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("unsortedUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("sortedUL");
  switching = true;
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {           
        shouldSwitch= true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString();
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: green;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: number;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-align: center;


  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

input {
  border: none;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.sortBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Assignment Two</title>
<body>
  <h1 style="color:white;"align="center"id="date"></h1>
  <h1 style="color:white;"align="center"id="time"></h1>

  <div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2 style="margin:5px">Enter a list of words</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Word...">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
    <span onclick="sortList()" class="sortBtn">Sort</span>
  </div>
  <p>Sorted</p>
  <ul id="sortedUL">
  </ul>
  <p>Unsorted</p>
  <ul id="unsortedUL">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're welcome. Maybe consider creating a function that create the HTML Node. It will be cleaner. Also could you upvote my answer please ? :)

Comment: No problem, I clicked upvote before but I thought it said it didn't record newbie upvotes so I didn't bother. I upvoted and switched your answer to the correct one because I ended up using your solution. However, the_hobbes solution does in fact work, I used yours when actually changing my code.

Answer (score 0):

While you need list you can use Javascript Array
Here you can have two Arrays which would be SortedList and UnsortedList
I have declare both the list globally so that you can sort one list and keep one list without change
Refer The Below Code for the Work Flow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName"/>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddToList()"/>
            <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="SortList()"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    var sortedList = [];
    var unsortedList = [];
    function AddToList() {
        var data = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
        sortedList.push(data);
        unsortedList.push(data);
    }

    function SortList() {
        sortedList.sort();
        sortedList.reverse();
        console.log(sortedList);
        console.log(unsortedList);
    }
</script>
```

Here I have created two buttons as you said
And Called a function to sort and other to add in the List.
As you said you need the Unsorted List to be as it is, So in the `SortList()` function we have printed `sortedList` and `unsortedList` Both two see a diffrence.

As expected `sortedList` will print the descending order data and `unsortedList` will print normal data.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to insert it into both lists as each word is added, i.e. where you have:

```
document.getElementById("sortedUL").appendChild(li);
```

you should add a second line like this:

```
document.getElementById("unsortedUL").appendChild(li.cloneNode(true));
```

The node cloning might be what you were missing if you tried it before, otherwise it would move the same element and it ends up in only one list. The 'true' argument makes a deep copy so that the text node underneath it is copied as well.

Incidentally, this whole operation would be a lot easier with jQuery, it's the kind of DOM manipulation that the library was meant for. However people jump to jQuery so quickly and it's good that you are doing it with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Yes this worked! I actually tried this a few days ago but I hadn't added the "(li.cloneNode(true)); so it didn't work at the time. Thanks so much!